# Is there a GCC preprocessor directive to check if the code is being compiled on a 64 bit machine?

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to do something like the following;

```
#ifdef 64-bit
    #define DECIMAL_FORMAT %ld
#else
    #define DECIMAL_FORMAT %d
#endif
.
intptr_t d;  
.
printf(“Some message with DECIMAL_FORMAT in the middle of it\n”, d);
```

The variable 'd' being of the type 'intptr_t' needs '%d' format specifier on 32 bit machines and format specifier '%ld' on 64 bit machines. I am looking a solution to be able to compile the code on both 32 bit machines and 64 bit machines without making changes to the GCC command line or the source code.

Answer (score 25):

I think __LP64__ might be what you're looking for.  See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html

Maybe a better way to go, though, is to use the %p specifier to printf() instead of %ld or %d.  Then you don't even have to worry what your pointer size is.

Answer (score 8):

You want to use the `PRI*` macros defined in `inttypes.h`. You enable them by defining `__STDC\_FORMAT\_MACROS`. You can then use

```
 intptr_t d = ... ;
 printf("This is an intptr_t: %" PRIxPTR "\n", d);
```

The `PRIxPTR` macro will expand to `llx` if `__WORDSIZE == 64`, and `lx` or `x` otherwise.

Comment: +1 really cool.  However, the results on my x86-64 Debian system are slightly different. 
"echo __WORDSIZE | g++ -xc++ -include limits.h -P -E -" returns 64. 
"echo PRIxPTR | g++ -xc++ -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -include inttypes.h -E - | tail -1" returns "l" "x".

Comment: Well, the PRI*-macros are c99, so if you can demonstrate that they are misbehaving on your machine your should probably report a bug to the debian people.

Comment: My guess is the following: "l" "x" is "lx", which is fine if pointers and `long` are both 64 bits or both 32 bits; "llx" is really needed to print a pointer only if `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(long long)` but `sizeof(long long) > sizeof(long)`

Answer (score 1):

A recommended solution is to make your application behave more predictably. If you make it dependent on the size of a memory pointer, you may have some undesirable surprises. Printf only understands a few types, if you must print a value for a type that you can't always ensure that it is really known, it is much better to convert it to something known.

```
printf("Some message with %ld in the middle of it\n", (long) d);
```

This is a good advice, and valid for any type. For example, to print a Unix PID (that is of type pid_t):

```
pid_t pid = fork();
printf("Fork returned %d.\n", (int) pid);
```

You don't have to know what is the type and size of pid, as long as the target type is large enough.

Comment: I agree with your general philosophy, but note that you shouldn't depend on pointers fitting into a long.  On 64-bit Windows, they don't (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(VS.71).aspx).  For pointers, "%p" is the right way (as Fred Larsen pointed out).