# How to determine architecture in platform neutral way?

Tags: c++, platform, bit

I have a C++ app that uses wxWidgets. Certain parts of the app differ for 32 and 64 bit hosts. Currently I use sizeof(void *), but is there a better way that uses conditional compilation and is platform neutral?

Comment: What kind of things differ? API calls or things like datatype sizes or what? Unless the API does something silly, you shouldn't need any trickery like that.

Comment: It loads a 32 bit dll for one and a 64 bit dll for the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically people use #defines to determine bitness (the exact define will depend on the compiler). This is better than a runtime approach using sizeof(void*).

As for platform neutral, well, some compilers are on multiple platforms..

Comment: What would that look like for gcc/Mingw32?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682934/is-there-a-gcc-preprocessor-directive-to-check-if-the-code-is-being-compiled-on-a

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your compiler you may have access to platform specific macros. Try to look up their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

All common compilers have predefined preprocessor macros that identify the platform. For example, if you are using GCC, you can check them all easily:

```
touch foo.h; g++ -E -dM foo.h
```

which yields among others

```
#define linux 1
#define __x86_64 1
```

for me, since I'm using a 64b linux at the moment, and

```
#define __APPLE__ 1
#define __i386 1
```

on a 32b OS X, I hear.

For Sun Studio 12, they are documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5267/6n7c46edt/index.html#bkaoe). Also, Sun Microsystems considers them as part of the API of the compiler so compatibility is ensured. For example, on my Solaris box, I have `__SunOS_5_10` and `__sparcv9` defined (implies 64b).

On AIX systems with the IBM xlc compiler, take a look at `/etc/vac.cfg` and its `options` keyword fields to find out the predefined macros. There are at least `_AIX` and more specific `_AIX61` as well as `_POWER` (on a 64b PPC) defined on a system where I have access.

On HP-UX and its aCC compiler, there's at least the `__ia64` macro on itanium. Some other aCC specific predefined macros are documented [here](http://www.docs.hp.com/en/1559/preprocess.htm#CPPMacPredef).

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using `sizeof()` where the size matters? The compiler will happily optimise it away to a constant.

Comment: But then what if the if-block uses architecture specific functions?

Comment: Surely they are platform specific, rather than architecture specific? in which case you can use the preprocessor macros.
If there really are architecture specific functions on the same platform(!) then you could use #if defined(), I suppose. That sounds very strange though.

Comment: No. For example, Microsoft's Text-to-Speech API is initialized two different ways for 32 bit and 64 bit mode.

Comment: Microsoft are a responsible for a lot of quality code, but unless there is a very good reason that sounds like the most mind-numbingly dumb design decision ever.