# How many variables can a javascript array hold?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript array that is dynamically populated. Example: Array name $testarr[] And I have a database that fills it with numbers like this $testarr[id]=number. As my database is constantly growing I need to know when the array will hit the roof and refuse to take any more variables

Comment: I put it to you that if you need to store this much data in JavaScript, you're doing something wrong and you should use Ajax lookups or server side pagination instead. (Provided you're talking about JavaScript in a browser. of course)

Comment: How many million items do you want to put there? I don't think there is a hard limit (well, maybe 2^53), I think the browsers and computers have different points at which they'll crash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum size of an Array in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154989/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is browser-specific, so you need to check with the browser documentation. There have actually been exploits that took advantage of this, as a large enough array would go beyond the maximum allowed to by the browser.

I believe your design is faulty, as if you need to hold this many variables in javascript, you should probably re-think your design.

EDIT: apparently there is a limit - 2^32 - 1 - but I believe you'll reach the limit imposed by the browser before you get to 2^32 - 1 elements in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it is unlimited only by system memory, although the `length` property fails if indices get larger than 1073741822 according to [this source of 1997](http://sharkysoft.com/tutorials/jsa/content/063.html).

Answer (score 2):

You're not dealing with a limitation of the `Array` javascript object, you're dealing with the memory limitation of the **browser/machine combo** that is running your scripts.