# Understanding js array/object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

The below code returns [ ] in the console:

```
var postdata = {};
$.each($('#form').serializeArray(), function() {
    postdata[this.name] = this.value;
}); 
var postdataarray = [];
var pnr = parseInt($("#field").val().replace("-","")); //is a number after the hyphen removed
postdataarray[pnr] = {};
postdataarray[pnr]["formdata"] = postdata;
console.log(postdataarray);
```

But changing var pnr to 100 just for testing returns the array/object ok. What am I not understanding?

Below is ok

```
var postdata = {};
$.each($('#form').serializeArray(), function() {
    postdata[this.name] = this.value;
}); 
var postdataarray = [];
var pnr = 100; //changed for testing
postdataarray[pnr] = {};
postdataarray[pnr]["formdata"] = postdata;
console.log(postdataarray);
```

Edit: My goal is to create an object from form data but adding a key before the form data, such as:

{"100":{formdata:
{field1:value1,
field2:value2,
etc...
}
}

Comment: Arrays and Objects are not the same thing. `{}` is object `[]` is array.

Comment: You comments are incorrect - the value retrieved from the input element is a **String** while 100 is a primitive (Number) - they are different data types.

Comment: is not number ... check, parseInt($("#field").val().replace("-",""))

Comment: have you console.logged typeof pnr in the above snippet. I think that replace will return a string

Comment: What exactly is the result of `$("#field").val().replace("-","")`? Please do `console.log(JSON.stringify(pnr))` and post the output.

Comment: @Bergi $("#field").val().replace("-","") returns a value such as 199912121234

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's returning a string such as `"199912121234"`. Try this: `typeof $("#field").val().replace("-","")` to see that.

Comment: @KevinLindmark Ah. That's outside the range of [valid array indices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12766422/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi aha seems to be so. ParseInt and typeof shows number så I guess it is too long then...

Comment: @KevinLindmark There's no `parseInt` in the code you posted, so we assumed it was a string. Doesn't actually matter, though.

Comment: @Bergi, correct. Tried with ParseInt and adjusted question above now for future reference.

Comment: "*Edit: My goal is to create an object*" - then, like @ScottMarcus wrote in the first comment, don't use an array there. (And don't name it `postdataarray` but `postdataobject` to avoid confusion).