# Loss of floating-point precision in JavaScript arrays as they get really large?

Tags: javascript, arrays, floating-point

I am relatively unfamiliar with JavaScript, and I was recently told that a JavaScript array contains a `length` variable of type `Number`. This length is automatically updated as the array is updated to the number of elements in the array.

However, I was also told that internally, JavaScript uses a 64-bit floating point representation for its `Number` class. We know that floating point arithmetic cannot exactly represent all integers within its range.

So my question is, what happens with large arrays, where `length + 1` cannot exactly represent the next largest integer in the sequence?

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154989/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-javascript) the maximum length of an Array is `4,294,967,295`. `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is `9,007,199,254,740,991` so you won't have to worry because the engine won't let you get that far

Comment: @RGraham Thank you, if you write that as an answer I will accept it. What happens when you reach that length? Does the interpreter just complain at you and not let you update the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154989/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-javascript) the maximum length of an Array is `4,294,967,295`. `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is `9,007,199,254,740,991` so you won't have to worry because the engine won't let you get that far, example:

```
new Array(4294967296); // RangeError: Invalid array length
```

Relevant part of the [spec](https://es5.github.io/#x15.4.5.1):

> 3. c. Let *newLen* be ToUint32(Desc.[[Value]]).
>      b. If *newLen* is not equal to ToNumber( Desc.[[Value]]), throw a RangeError exception

So given our example length `4294967296`:

```
var length = 4294967296;
var int32length = length >>> 0; // Convert to int32
int32length === 0; // Can't represent this as int32
length !== int32length; // Therefore RangeException
```

Comment: @Shaktal You're welcome. This seems like it's right, but someone with more knowledge of JS internals may prove me wrong!

Comment: It seems to make logical sense, I will wait for a while before accepting to make sure though!

Comment: It's worth remembering that an array under the hood is just like any other JavaScript object and you can trick it like so. var tmp = []; tmp[0] = "0"; tmp[4294967294] = "4294967294"; console.log(tmp); Array [ "0", <9 empty slots>, 4294967285 more… ] which means you can 'fake' the size by only populating two elements of the array, the first, and the last.

Comment: @NeilMunro But `var temp = [0]; temp[4294967296]; temp.length === 1;`, so you can't get a true length like that. All you're doing there is putting a string key onto an object posing as an array

Comment: It's not an object posing as an array, an array is just syntactic sugar around a regular object: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf Page 95. "An array is an exotic object that gives special treatment to array index property keys". It's just a little caveat of the... Special way JavaScript treats arrays that under certain circumstances might be useful to know.

Comment: I think we're both saying the same thing :) i.e. An array is an object posing as what is traditionally thought of as an "array" in other languages

Answer (score 0):

The maximum length of an array according to the ECMA-262 5th Edition specification is bound by an unsigned 32-bit integer due to the ToUint32 abstract operation, so the longest possible array could have 232-1 = 4,294,967,295 = 4.29 billion elements. This is according to [Maximum size of an Array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154989/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-javascript)..

so I guess @RGraham is right