# DataStore in Single Page Apps

Tags: javascript, single-page-application

Regardless of the framework or library in use, the amount of data downloaded from internet and stored in a JavaScript array gets larger and larger.

The question is: What is the hard limit on how much data such an Array/Object can hold? What happens when the limit is reached? Does Facebook ever crash because of such a problem?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what Facebook has to do with it.

Comment: If your question is what the maximum size of a Javascript array is in general, it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154989/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: The tag `facebook` is for questions that specifically pertain to development for the FB platform. Since your’s doesn’t seem to do that, I removed the tag. (If you want to add it back in again, then please edit your question as well, so that the connection to _development for the FB platform_ becomes clear.)