# Javascript array seems empty after pushing some value into it with custom keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I faced a strange problem, even if I push some content to an array with custom index keys, its still show as an empty array. If I know the index then I can reach the content.

```
function search (source, pattern) {
  let regexp    = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');
  let messages  = [];
  let match;

  while ((match = regexp.exec(source)) !== null) {
    let date  = match[2];
    let ms    = parseDate(date).getTime();
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(messages[ms]) !== '[object Array]')
      messages[ms] = [];

    messages[ms].push(match[0])
  }
  console.log(messages);
  console.log(messages[1414860420000]);
}
```

Calling this on my source with my pattern will wind multiple matches and it will push them into the correct sub array in the main array. But if after this I try `console.log(messages);` it will return `[ ]` instead of a list of `[object Array]`s. However calling an existing key I can reach the data inside the `messages` array. What am I missing? Why the content is "not visible" in the array?

**EDIT:**

The exact reason why the values attached as a property and not as an member of the array is because the numbers I wanted to use are bigger than [the maximum allowed size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154989/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-javascript)

So while this works:

```js
var fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi'];

fruits[23] = 'pear';

document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = fruits.toString();
```

```html
<p></p>
```

This wont work:

```js
var fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi'];

fruits[53454657567573] = 'pear';

document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = fruits.toString();
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `let messages  = [];` to `let messages  = {};`  You aren't using `messages` as an array.  You are using it as an object to store property/values on.  While an array is also an object so the properties do get stored on the array, `console.log()` gets fooled when you use an array rather than a plain object.

`console.log()` thinks you want to view the contents of the array.  But there are no actual array elements on `messages`.  You will see that `messages.length === 0`.  The array is actually empty which is what `console.log(messages)` shows you.

On the other hand, if you make messages a plain object, then `console.log()` will show you the property/value pairs on the object.

---

FYI, this won't change the behavior, but you could simplify by changing this:

```
if(Object.prototype.toString.call(messages[ms]) !== '[object Array]')
```

to this:

```
if (!messages[ms])
```

since all you're trying to see is whether the property has been previously initialized to an array or not.

Comment: There is a typo, I guess u wanted to write `if (!messages[ms])` but I cant edit it.