# Mongoose insertMany limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose 4.4 now has an `insertMany` function which lets you validate an array of documents and insert them if valid all with one operation, rather than one for each document:

`var arr = [{ name: 'Star Wars' }, { name: 'The Empire Strikes Back' }];
Movies.insertMany(arr, function(error, docs) {});`

If I have a very large array, should I batch these? Or is there no limit on the size or array?

For example, I want to create a new document for every Movie, and I have 10,000 movies.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd recommend based on personal experience, batch of 100-200 gives you good blend of performance without putting strain on your system.

insertMany group of operations can have at most 1000 operations. If a group exceeds this limit, MongoDB will divide the group into smaller groups of 1000 or less. For example, if the queue consists of 2000 operations, MongoDB creates 2 groups, each with 1000 operations.

The sizes and grouping mechanics are internal performance details and are subject to change in future versions.

Executing an ordered list of operations on a sharded collection will generally be slower than executing an unordered list since with an ordered list, each operation must wait for the previous operation to finish.

Comment: this is not up to date - starting with v3.6 the batch size is 100,000

Answer (score 18):

**Mongo 3.6 update:**

The limit for `insertMany()` has [increased in Mongo 3.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#execution-of-operations) from `1000` to `100,000`.
Meaning that now, groups above `100,000` operations will be divided into smaller groups accordingly.
For example: a queue that has `200,000` operations will be split and Mongo will create 2 groups of `100,000` each.

Comment: I tried adding 50000 at once but sadly it was slow. I tried with 1000 and it was faster.

Comment: @AshokDey, i never said it would be faster :)  never the less - that might depend on the type of your machine(amount of RAM, disk writes etc...). Are you sending the data to a different server using `async/await`? that also might cause it to be slower.

Comment: Ahh.. seems like I forgot to paste the URL of the Github repo, here it is: https://github.com/ashokdey/scale
You can know about the use case in the Readme and I would be happy to see you as a collaborator. For my use case, it was quicker compared to 50k insert at a time.

Comment: Is there some limit on the total size of the documents too?

Comment: @KaliCharan Yes, according to MongoDB's official docs the size limit for every document is 16MB, see here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/
You can increase the size limit (see the same link) but for storing such large documents MongoDB might not be the optimal choice and you would rather use a cloud storage of some sort (S3, GCS etc...).

Answer (score 7):

[The method](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/65e744b9fa7066495ab965b7be3c53c51ca2b00b/lib/model.js#L1824) takes that array and starts inserting them through the insertMany method in MongoDB, so the size of the array itself actually depends on how much your [machine can handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154989/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-javascript).

But please note that there is another point, which is not a limitation but something worth keeping into consideration, on how MongoDB deals with multiple operations, by default it handles a [batch of 1000 operations](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) at a time and splits whats more than that.