# MongoDB insetMany not inserting all documents when document length is over 50k

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to add a list of contacts to my db. I am using inertMany to do so. Every thing works fine if amount of contacts i am adding is within 50k. if it exceeds that not all data is being save to db. the response i get after insert is `{ ok: 1, n: 1047 }`
. Anybody know why this is happening ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose insertMany limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042967/mongoose-insertmany-limit)

Comment: You should use `initializeOrderedBulkOp()` instead