# the max length of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've met a problem in learning javascript.Here is my code:

```
var arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i <4294967296; i=i+1){
    arr[i] = 1;}
```

But both in chrome and firefox,it ended up with something wrong.I know that the max length of an array is 4294967295(2^32-1) in javascript,when i changed 4294967296 to  4294967295, 4294967294 , or a little more smaller,it still didn't work.I also tested it in Node.js,after a while of executing,it just ended with:

```
FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I don't know why?

Comment: Like the error says, you're running out of memory.

Comment: Your pc doesn't have enough addressable memory to allocate.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154989/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: The theoretical maximum is not, necessarily, the same as the practical maximum which is based on available memory and the JavaScript engine itself.

Comment: You're truing to make an array with over 4 billion 8-byte numbers. At the very minimum, that will consume 32 gigabytes of memory.

Comment: I think you're out of memory, bro.

Answer (score 0):

1 is an integer and is 4 bytes or 8 bytes long in memory (depending on your OS), so you must not have 4M * this length bytes available in memory.

Comment: What you really mean is 4G?I think that is the reason.