# Is this a bug in JSFiddle and Codepen, or in Highcharts, or a limitation of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jsfiddle, codepen

I am creating a [heatmap with Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap). I tested on a 5x5 map and [I get the expected heatmap](http://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/qz3szpcy/).

I then tested a larger one and [the resulting heatmap is incorrect](http://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/Lt14afae/). I also tried it in CodePen, [with same (incorrect) result](https://codepen.io/WoJWoJ/pen/WZvKOE).

<del>Something strange is also happening somewhere in the large Array when using Codepen:</del> (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46243375/903011) for that point, which explains why the highlighting stops)

[image]

I have a few possibilities:

- it could be a browser problem. I tested with Chrome and Firefox and get the same error
- it could be a JavaScript limitation on the size of the Array <del>(the highlighting of the code is chnaging in Codepen so maybe)</del>. [It looks like it is not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6155063/903011).
- it could be a bug in JSFiddle and Codepen. I doubt it as the issue is the same in both sandboxes.
- it could be a bug with Highcharts. This I do not know - my code is not exotic (even though somehow large) so that should have been caught earlier. But this one looks like the most probable.

```html
This is a fake snippet as the question requires one but it is not useful in this case
```

Answer (score 1):

[CodeMirror](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror) (which is the editor of codepen) support the `maxHighlightLength`, which tells the editor the maximum length of characters the editor should highlight.

The `default` value of that variable is `10000`, and in your specific case the line is longer than this value.

Comment: Yes, this was my guess too, but if I break that array into several smaller lines, it's highlighted correctly, but still heatmap is empty. Same on jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you - I will strike the points related to the highlighting but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Issue here is that you need to tell highcharts the scale of the yAxis. To do this set it to the min = 0 and max = the number of categories - 1:

```
...
  yAxis: {
    categories: ['10.233.86.12', '10.233.84.72', '10.2.0.71', '10.90.13.175', '10.233.84.57', '10.91.66.24', '255.255.255.255', '224.0.0.252', '10.233.86.34', '10.233.80.60', '10.112.0.142', '10.35.24.33', '10.130.37.22', '10.20.3.16', '10.233.84.83', '10.70.1.79', '10.6.41.78', '10.89.3.109', '10.118.68.133', '192.168.0.11', '10.70.0.253', '10.10.68.56'],
    title: null,
    min: 0,
    max: 21
  },
...
```

Note that you should also tell it to show every category which should be done by increasing height of chart so labels do not overlap.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug. Simply the number of points exceeds the default value of the `turboThreshold` property (see the API Reference section). Increase the number of the `turboThreshold` and heatmap will display correctly.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.turboThreshold

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/p4z094g9/