# Maximum depth of an Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I was experimented one day when I came across this question in Stack Overflow and got curious: [Maximum size of an Array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154989/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-javascript) (**Maximum size of an Array in JavaScript**).

Question is, what is the **Maximum depth of an Array in JavaScript**?

By depth I mean how much can you nest an array within an array until JavaScript gives up?

```
[1]           // Depth Level: 1
[1, [2]]      // Depth Level: 2
[1, [2, [3]]] // Depth Level: 3
[1, [...]]    // Depth Level: x?
```

Is it machine-dependent, is it based on the compiler?

No, I'm not sure if there's any practical use for this but it's still something I'm curious about nonetheless.

Comment: `let x = [], y = [x]; x[0] = y;` - infinite.

Comment: Or, `x = [];  x.push(x);` also makes an array with infinite depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you can nest *different* arrays until you run out of memory, but you can nest the same array and get an effectively infinite depth array.

```
var x = [ ];
x.push(x);

x[0][0][0](...)[0]; // Now valid
```

This shows up as `[ [Circular] ]` in most debuggers because it's what's called a "circular reference", as in the array contains itself.

This is similar to how you can have self-referential objects:

```
var x = { };
x.x = x;

// { x: [Circular] }

x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x(...).x; // Now valid
```

JavaScript itself doesn't really care what depth something is, the language has no intrinsic limit. Sometimes circular references are a feature, like `x.y` refers to something that refers back to `x` for convenience, a way of showing mutual association. That's *technically* infinite depth, but it's unlikely you'd use it that way.

Here's a simple example of that phenomenon:

```
var x = { };
var y = { };

x.y = y;
y.x = x;

x.y.x.y.x.y; // Pointless, but valid.
```

Comment: Odd how there's a limit to array length, but not depth. Anyways, thanks. I really appreciate the answer.

Comment: @Lapys The array length is represented as an unsigned 32 bit integer, so the length must be able to fit into 4 bytes. With depth, there doesn't really need to be a limit. If `x.x` just points to itself, then it has no problem just fetching the thing at `x`'s address and returning it to you.

Comment: @pushkin While that's a good point, is that still the case in 64-bit versions of JavaScript? That sounds like an implementation quirk unless it's defined in the standard, so it's more a practical limit that could change than a theoretical one.

Comment: @tadman I'm not sure what you mean by 64-bit version of JavaScript. It's true according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length). Regarding the max length, yes, it's a practical limit that could change.

Comment: @pushkin I mean that in other languages `size_t` varies depending on the ISA, so 64-bit versions have larger max-lengths than their 32-bit counterparts. If JavaScript sticks with 32-bit in both cases that seems odd.

Comment: @tadman Ah. It kind of seems like that according to the docs. I guess the benefit is that you don't have to worry about different behavior on different systems - just fix it at 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

tadman gave an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51071563/3479456) from the runtime perspective (infinite depth), but from a compile-time perspective, there is a limit. It's not one that's built into JavaScript (as far as I know), but consider what the compiler has to do to compile your code.

```
[1, [2, [3]]]
```

The compiler needs to turn the above expression into an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). Roughly:

```
[ , ]
 /\
1 [ , ]
   /\
  2 [3]
```

If the compiler runs out of memory when creating those nodes, because there are too many nodes/expressions, then it will crash and your program won't compile. In the case of JavaScript, since it uses a [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation), I guess it's a compilation error that happens at runtime.