# what is the google apps script setValues() maximum batch size?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running a setValues() function for a sheet with massive data count (20,000 * 50) so I finished the data in batch then used the setValues() function to update the sheet at once but the function is updating data in a manner that looks like (x * 50) sequentially, so I wanted to know the limitation of the maximum cells updated at once when using this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when the values are put to the sheet using `setValues`, at first, the cells are kept and the values are put to the cells. When I had tested the maximum number of cells for putting the values using `setValues` before, 2,625,000 cells could be put. But, when I tested over 2,635,000 cells, an error of `Exceeded maximum execution time` occurred. So at that time, I had resulted that the maximum cells were between 2,625,000 and 2,635,000. By the way, when 4,000,000 cells are tested, it was found that the 4,000,000 cells are kept in the destination sheet while the values couldn't be put. This is the result in my environment.

So, in the case of `20,000 * 50`, I thought that 1,000,000 cells can be put with `setValues`. But I'm worried that when such data is put with `setValues`, the process cost was high. For example, after the script is finished and I checked the sheet, I was required to wait to completely put the values. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.

In this case, when Sheets API instead of Spreadsheet service (`SpreadsheetApp`) is used for putting the values to the sheet, such an issue could be removed. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

From the above situation, in your situation, as a workaround, how about putting the values using Sheets API instead of `setValues` of Spreadsheet service?

#### Reference:

- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

Comment: thank you, from the graphs there I figured I can cut my execution time to half of what it is now, but what could be a limitation using the sheets API instead of the spreadsheet service?

Comment: @Youssef Ahmed Thank you for replying. About your additional question of `but what could be a limitation using the sheets API instead of the spreadsheet service?`, you can see "Usage limits" at [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/limits). But I thought that your situation might be able to be achieved using one API call. In that case, I think that this limitation will not be affected.

Answer (score 1):

### There is no direct maximum for `setValues()`, but you might want to consider the following three points:

- There is a (very high) [maximum size of an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154989/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-javascript).
- There is a [maximum amount of columns, cells and new rows](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/88183868/google-sheets-limitations?hl=en) in a Google spreadsheet.
- There is a maximum [script runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) and your function might time out before `setValues()` finished executing.

Of those 3 limits the amount of values you can set with one `setValues()` call is most likely to be limited by the maximum script execution time.

Comment: yes I am aware of these limits, I just didn't know that setValues() will just keep setting values sequentially until runtime is exceeded instead of setting the whole range at once so I wanted to know the limit for the maximum number of cells that could be set at once