# Is there a a define for 64 bit in gcc

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting 64bit compile in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272825/detecting-64bit-compile-in-c)

I want my program to run on both 32 bit and 64 bit Linux OS. So In my C code, I want the compiler to know when it is compiling for a 32 bit and 64 bit architecture. So, I need something like that

```
#ifdef X64
...
#else
...
#endif
```

Is there any such *define* in *gcc*?

Comment: What parts of your code have to be different depending on whether you're on a 32-bit or 64-bit system?  Can you modify it so it doesn't care?  For example, if you need an integer type of a particular width, take a look at `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: @KeithThompson - it's not only about the integers (which sucks in C/C++, and even after `<stdint.h>` - MSVC, anyone?). For example you may have a general piece of code, which has to choose different libraries loaded at runtime through `dlopen`... Of course you can go with `sizeof(void*)`, as far as it gets you.

Comment: @TomaszGandor: I don't know what you're saying "sucks", but this probably isn't the place to discuss it. In any case, the meaning of "32-bit" and "64-bit" when applied to systems is not at all clear. The OP probably needs to distinguish between x86 and x86_64 architectures. Choosing which library to open is a more complex question than 32-bit vs. 64-bit.

Comment: @KeithThompson - you're right - it was probably about just distinguishing i386 from amd64 (they come under different names, i don't like underscores;) What sucks? For example this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126279/c99-stdint-h-header-and-ms-visual-studio You may think: "What's the big deal?". Well, if you're writing an application - nothing, just use the newer compiler. But - men sometimes write libraries. And a library needs to work with compiler across the board. You need to work without `<stdint.h>` until the last user of VS 2008 dies...

Comment: @TomaszGandor: If `<stdint.h>` is missing, you can provide your own, as mentioned in [the accepted answer] to that question as well as [here](http://www.lysator.liu.se/(nobg)/c/q8/index.html). (Blame Microsoft, not C or C++.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know of these:

```
__i386__    
__x86_64__
```

I don't know how reliable they are.

The best option would be adding `-DMY_32BIT` to the Makefile's compile line when compiling for 32 bits and checking for `MY_32BIT` on your code. That way you can be sure.

Answer (score 4):

There is __WORDSIZE in limits.h:

```
#include <limits.h>
#if ( __WORDSIZE == 64 )
#define BUILD_64   1
#endif
```

This is relatively portable (due to POSIX), but may fail in obscure environments or on windows.

Answer (score 3):

Look [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/predef/index.php?title=Architectures#AMD64):

```
#ifdef __x86_64
...
#endif
```