# How to check a execute file is 64 bit in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, process

I like understand a execute file is 64 bit or no.
I want to understand a run process in Linux is 64 bit or 32 bit with c++.
I do not want to use "file" command.
for example:
File -L bash

Comment: The answer is a bit unclear. You want to detect whether a file in the filesystem is a 32/64 executable? Or detect whether your own process will be 32/64?

Comment: detect whether own process will be 32/64

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting 64bit compile in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272825/detecting-64bit-compile-in-c)

Comment: Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505582/determining-32-vs-64-bit-in-c)

Comment: NO i need detect other process is OS.Sorry I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use elfio lib.
this is a link for that: (http://elfio.sourceforge.net)

Comment: Rather than checking the binary, you can at compile time determine the result by using preprocessor macros expanded by the compiler. See the linked questions marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

You need to parse the elf header.
You can write your own parser, or use a dedicated library such as this one: http://elfio.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thanks but i need a simple way for example use proc directory.

Comment: Did you even look at that library?  It couldn't be simpler.

Comment: Just parse the ELF header of `/proc/$PID/exe`

Answer (score 0):

you can use: `readelf -h <executable file name>`