# How can I know the bit count of a cpu/os in C

Tags: c, linux, sizeof, bitcount

I know how to get the bit count of a cpu or an operation system with shell.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep lm #-> get bit count of a cpu
uname -a                    #-> get bit count of an operation system
```

However, how can we get the bit count of those in a C program. 
This is an interview question and my solution is as follow:

```
int *ptr;
printf("%d\n", sizeof(ptr)*8);
```

But the interviewer said that was wrong. So, what is the correct answer?

Comment: While the size of a pointer *often* follow the "size" of the platform, this is not always true. The only way is to query the operating system using OS native functions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg which OS native functions can we use?

Comment: Depends on the operating system of course.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg er.. I'm sorry. Let's assumed the operation system is Linux.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting 64bit compile in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272825/detecting-64bit-compile-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX provides a C function [uname](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html) as well. You can get similar result like the shell command `uname`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>

int main(){
    struct utsname buf;
    uname(&buf);
    printf("sysname: %s\nversion: %s\nmachine: %s\n ", buf.sysname, buf.version, buf.machine);
    return 0;
}
```

Output on my machine:

```
sysname: Linux
version: #1 SMP Tue Oct 2 22:01:37 EDT 2012
machine: i686
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, a simple way is to do e.g. [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) with the [`uname -m`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uname) command and parse the output.

Another way is to look at the source for the `uname` command (as it's readily available) and implement something based on that directly.