# Compile C++ as 64Bit with CLion

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, mingw-w64, clion

I have a c++ application that runs a memory-consuming algorithm.

It crushes with error : **terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'** after the allocated memory reaches about 2GB.

I want to compile it as 64Bit so it could allocate more memory from my 64Bit/8GB Ram machine.

How it can be done?

Im working with CLion, building with CMake and using mingw version:
**mingw-w64\i686-4.8.3-posix-dwarf-rt_v3-rev2**
btw - the wingw is installed under `C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64` is this related to the issue?

I've been looking here:
[Detecting 64bit compile in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272825/detecting-64bit-compile-in-c)
and (not suprisingly) I can see that my application does not have the `__x86_64__`

Comment: Doesn't -m64 do the trick?

Comment: mmm i dont know where should i put it?

Comment: As an argument to your compiler invocation string. Somewhere in CMake definitions.

Comment: ill check it in about an hour and tell you

Comment: If you can compile and run your application on some POSIX system, try using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). You might have some [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).If possible, compile it with [GCC 5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) and use some `-fsanitize=` options during the debugging phase (in addition of `-Wall -Wextra -g`)

Comment: @SergeyA you where right, it worked! '-m64' did the trick, now I discovered that I need to change the toolchain from i686 to x86_64. Thanks!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks for your advice, I'll check that. I kinda expected the huge memory consumption since Im working on an algorithm that builds HUGE graph with bilions of nodes

Comment: @SergeyA do you want to post your answer so I will accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by OP, posting my comment as an answer: for this you need to pass -m64 option to compiler/linker.

Answer (score 4):

You have to tell CLion to use MinGW-w64 to build your CMake project.

You dont have to change your CMake project configuration. It would be counterproductive limiting your CMake project by a fixed machine architecture, if you can instead easily tell your compiler which architecture to build for or use an appropriate compiler (`MinGW-w64`).

This post shows you how to do that:

https://dev.my-gate.net/2014/09/15/how-to-use-mingw-w64-with-clion/

Excerpt from this post:

> Here are the few steps to make it work:
>
> 1. Get your MinGW-w64 compiler installed somewhere.
> 2. Create a file with the path [MinGW-w64 dir]/include/_mingw.h and the content shown below.
> 3. Point CLion to your [MinGW-w64 dir] and watch how CLion
>      recognizes your MinGW setup.
>      [image: Image screenshoted from this post]

After building your executable, you can check its architecture with the unix command `file`, which should be available to you since you are using mingw.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant content from that blog into your answer in case the blog disappears?