# Preprocessor macro to identify 64bit

Tags: gcc

Is there a gcc macro that allows me to identify whether something is being compiled in 64bit mode?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272825/detecting-64bit-compile-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting 64bit compile in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5272825/608639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate Question:
[Is there a GCC preprocessor directive to check if the code is being compiled on a 64 bit machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682934/is-there-a-gcc-preprocessor-directive-to-check-if-the-code-is-being-compiled-on)

`__LP64__` 
Seems to be what you want.

Comment: Note that on Windows, 64bit compiles are indicated by `__LLP64__` (yes, even with `gcc`). See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/31/363790.aspx for details.

Answer (score 1):

And you could also, at least on Linux,

```
  #include <features.h>
  #include <endian.h>    // perhaps you skip that
  #include <limits.h>
  #include <stdint.h>
```

Then `<bits/workdsize.h>` gets included and gives you `__WORDSIZE` (either 64 or 32)

But why do you ask and why using the standard types provided by `<stdint.h>` is not enough for you?